# Visual Studio Online using Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

[Visual Studio Online](https://online.visualstudio.com/) allows you to create remote environments on the fly, but the default distribution is Debian. 
How can I change it to Ubuntu? 
I tried to use devcontainer.json file, but it did not seem to be working;
the created environment `lsb_release -a` command output  is still Debian.